# How to .pack a list in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Very new to programming
I made a list and in the list is a label with a bunch of variables.
but when i tried to pack the list, error would come up saying 
"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'pack'"

Now i am lost as to how to pack the label

```
self.qrl=[]
        for i in range (10):
            self.qrl.append(Label(self.results_content_frame,text=("For question "+str(self.counter)+" your answer was "+str(self.ans1)+", correct answer was "+str(self.calc_answer)+" therefore your answer was "+self.correct_answer+"."),font=("Calibri", "12")))
            self.qrl.pack()
```

Comment: do you mean `self.qrl[0].pack()` to pack  the Label? Lists don't have a pack method, `self.qrl[0]` is the element inside the list.

Comment: so could I use the variable like [k] instead of 0 to print out the kth  label in the list?

Comment: Keeping your lines' length under 80 characters will make your code more readable

Comment: yes exactly. list[0],list[1] etc..

Comment: Thanks :) and I'll make sure to keep it so the code stays on the next time I ask for help kroolik

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `self.qrl.pack()` and just cycle through the list.

```
for i in range (0, len(self.qrl)):
    self.qrl[i].pack()
```

Basically, it will check the list for objects (in your case, Labels) and for every object it finds, it will pack it onto the window.

Comment: Your first suggestion is a bad one - `.pack` doesn't return anything, so you will fill `self.qrl` with `None` and lose the references to the labels.